# How do I use the formatted value of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, date

I have a cell `A1` containing a date formatted as date so that it shows `28.Oct`.

I want to use that formatted date embedded into a piece of text like this: "Today is the 28.Oct and it is sunny".

I have written `="Today is the"&A1&" and it is sunny"`, but that looses the formatting and I just get a large number instead of the date and month name.

I would like to reference the already-formatted content of `A1` as a text string, not the actual number representing the time. How do I do that?

Comment: Thank you for the TEXT(...) formatting. I tried it earlier but did not get it to work. Now I realized it is a locale issue. So now the question is how to specify different locale for each worksheet in the same workbook.

Comment: You include the appropriate locale code in the *format_text* argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
="Today is the " & TEXT(A1,"d\.mmm") & " and it is sunny"
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my case as date codes "d" and "mmm" depend on Excel locale (in Spanish, Japanese, Ukrainian its different, like "д", "ttt" etc, so they won't work in some Excel locales).